# adding data attribute to option value in Drupal 6

Tags: webforms, forms

I have a form, like this:

```
        $form['my_case_type_list']=array(
            '#type'=>'select',
            '#title' => 'Issue Type',
            '#options' => $my_list,
            '#multiple' => false,
            '#attributes'=>array('size'=>1),
            '#weight'=>2,
        );
```

where $my_list is an array, like this:

```
$array[0] = 'string 1'
$array[1] = 'string 2'
$array[2] = 'string 3'
```

This renders a dropdown list with the array key as the option value and the array value as the option text.  I want to use a multi-dimensional array to also provide each option with a data id.  An array like this:

```
$return_array[0] = array('name' =>'string 1', 'description'=>'description for string 1');
$return_array[1] = array('name' =>'string 2', 'description'=>'description for string 2');
$return_array[2] = array('name' =>'string 3', 'description'=>'description for string 3');
```

and have the description field be used, in the option value, as a data attribute.  So, it would be rendered like this:

```
<select name="my_case_type_list" size="1" class="form-select" id="edit-my-case-type-list">
    <option data-desc='description for string 1' value="0">String 1</option>
    <option data-desc='description for string 2'  value="1">String 2</option>
    <option data-desc='description for string 3'  value="2">String 3</option>
</select>
```

Is this even possible?  Can you assign a multi-dim array to a form?  When I do, it just create option groups and each dimension of the array becomes an option.

thanks
jason

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked previously for [Drupal 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9261224/adding-attribute-to-option-element-using-forms-api-drupal-7/9264589#9264589) and there is no great answer so it's unlikely to be possible in Drupal 6 the answer seems to be implementing a custom [theme_select](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/theme_select/6)